# SSIS File System Task - Create Folder - "The network path was not found"

Tags: deployment, ssis, ssis-connection-manager

I've recently created an SSIS Project and deployed that project to a folder in SSISDB. I've tested this project and I am able to run it end-to-end in Visual Studio successfully.

However, when I run the deployed version I get an error: "The network path was not found". I view the reports of the execution and notice that it relates to the File System Task; specifically I configured it to create a new folder and I configured the Source Connection as a File Connection in the File System Task editor.

So in my Connection Managers window I have 3 connections:

1. SQL Server
2. Excel
3. File Connection (used in File System Task; basically the directory I want the Folder to be created in)

I've noticed that 1 and 2 are deployed to SSISDB but not 3. I'm guessing this is the cause of my problems. Question is why is 3 (the file connection) not deploying to SSISDB? I have no clue. I've searched around and tried different things.

Thanks

PS- Connection Manager
[image]

Comment: Hi, you need to build a generic file connection string with the path to the relevant server, for example; **\\server\C$\Folder\FILE.txt** 
and make sure that the server that you deployed to, have permission to this path.

Comment: Hi @ Benzi. I already had the connection manager to the directory where I wanted to create the new folder called 'NewFolder' setup. Please see my picture edit in the original comment...